# How to read nested objects from appsettings?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, appsettings

In my .NET Core application, I am trying to read data from `appsettings.json`.

I have this configuration in `appsettings.json`:

```
"ServiceDetails": {
   "CellDetails": {
     "ScenarioName": [ 4, 5 ],
     "ServiceName": [ 5, 5 ]
   }
}
```

I would like to read this and convert into list like this:

```
scenario name, 4,5
service name, 5,5
```

Model class for the above list:

```
public class CellDetails
{
     public string CellKeyValue { get; set; }
     public int Row { get; set; }
     public int Column { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying something like this

```
var serverUrl = configuration.GetSection("ServiceDetails")
                     .GetSection("CellDetails").Get<string[]>();
```

Above code doesn't work, can someone help me to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
var myArray = configuration.GetSection("ServiceDetails:CellDetails:ScenarioName").Get<int[]>();
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

Try to create a model ServiceDetails like:

```
public class ServiceDetails
{
    public List<CellDetails> CellDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Then in appsettings.json :

```
"ServiceDetails": {
  "CellDetails": [
    {
      "CellKeyValue": "ScenarioName",
      "Row": 4,
      "Column": 5
    },
    {
      "CellKeyValue": "ServiceName",
      "Row": 5,
      "Column": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Then

```
var myArray = configuration.GetSection("ServiceDetails:CellDetails").Get<List<CellDetails>>() ;
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Qing Guo, I have bit updated my question.  I want to have output as list mentioned in the above question

Comment: Hi @Qing Guo, I would like to bind ScenarioName and servicename to the CellKeyValue property in the model CellDetails. Similarlty for row and columns.  Inside celldetails i may have multiple objects and i want to get it as list

Comment: Hi@Niranjan , If you want to " bind ScenarioName and servicename to the CellKeyValue property in the model CellDetails. Similarlty for row and columns " Please have a look at my update.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Recommended way do this, but if you don't change the schema this will be helpful:

```
var arr = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ServiceDetails:CellDetails").GetChildren();

foreach (var item in arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " : "+ item.GetSection("0").Value + ", "+ item.GetSection("1").Value);
}
```

And this is the output:

[image: output]